# unable to connect remote mongo db server

Tags: mongodb, remote-access, remote-server

I am not able to connect to mongodb server which is running on a remote machine on windows,
I started mongod on on the remote machine by taking remote access through Remote Desktop Connection on the command prompt(not as a service)it is showing waiting for connecting on port 27017...

and when i try to connect from local machine through mongo 234.345.212.60:27017(i changed actual ip here i am not sure is it safe or not)
well when i press enter it shows [image]

I have tried to start mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 as well but no benefit.

i have also checked the port 27017 on the remote machine is open over UDP not as TCP i have checked through [https://support.nightlydev.org/tcp-udp-port-scan][2] this site,
one more thing i think i should mention here i am not using any authentication(--auth) i am connecting without any --auth and i a am able to connect this way of my all system connected through LAN but not that particular machine which somewhere else.
i have installed the same version of mongodb both side(Client and Remote machine).

after trying a lot still a am not able to connect now i am thinking is it even possible to connect remote mongodb over UDP port and without --auth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i am able to connect to remote mongodb server,
the issue was with the port I was connecting,
I was connecting to a port which was open over UDP but when I make that port changed over TCP I connect very easily(means I talked to my networking team and asked them to make the port 27017 available over TCP).

so moral of the story you can not connect mongodb remote server over UDP port through public ip or through the internet.

Comment: Hey.. my MongoD runs on TCP port. yet I am not able to connect to the remote MongoDb server. Any thing else that you did there?

Comment: make sure your remote machine is accessible through the public IP